# I need help converting a code form Fortran to C

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran

I am new in programming. I need to convert a Fortran 95 file into a C file. At the beginning of the Fortran file I have a module that contains a bunch of variables that are used inside various functions (don't mind the comments):

```
MODULE data

IMPLICIT NONE
SAVE

DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: tmax_dsmc  = 450.D0     ! durata simulazione
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: tim_dsmc   = 150.D0     ! istante inizio campionamento
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: dt_dsmc    = 0.05D0     ! passo temporale
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: alpha_dsmc = 0.02D0     ! gradiente velocita'
```

Is there a way to replicate this in C? I know that I could use the command `#define variable x` but I don't know if it is correct; my goal is to have these constants defined somewhere in the code so that if I modify one, every single part of the program could knows the new value I have assigned. Of course I can define each constant in every function I have in my code but it would be a great waste of time.

Comment: `#define` is for constants, not for variables. If you change them later, do something like `[type] x = [value]`, where [type] is whatever type you want (int, float, double, char, etc), and value is the value to assign to it.

Comment: `PARAMETER` are FORTRAN constants no ? So why would you like to modify them  in C ? You don't really want to translate or am I wrong ?

Comment: sorry about my vocabulary but I am not a program expert; the idea is to have some parameters at the beginning of the code so they are seen by the whole program; in case I change one of them, every function and the main know the new value I set

Comment: If I understand well your problem, you may have a look at my answer.

Comment: I would recommend getting a good textbook on C. The questions you are likely to encounter will likely be answered there. The classic would be Kernighan&Richie, "The C Programming Language", but get the second edition (which includes the first ANSI standard).  If you also don't know Fortran, then get a good textbook on Fortran, too.  However, you will encounter many problems, especially if the Fortran program you are trying to translate uses multidimensional arrays and/or is written in an ideomatic style which uses many of modern Fortran's features such as assumed-shape arrays.

Comment: I am afraid converting a substantial amount of code from one language to another is quite hopeless, if you don't know at least one of the languages well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define constant in C, you can use `#define PI 3.1415926`. If you don't want to duplicate this everywhere, then you can use `#include`s like this:

First a header (in a file named `MyConsts.h`):

```
/* My constants */
#define PI 3.1415926
```

then a module (in some `.c` file):

```
/* A module */
#include "MyConsts.h" // include here the contents of the file
...
double p = 2*PI*r;
...
```

and another one (in another `.c` file):

```
/* Another module */
#include "MyConsts.h" // include here the contents of the file
...
double s = PI*r*r;
...
```

If you use a clean compilation procedure by describing the dependencies in a `Makefile` for example, then every modification made in `MyConsts.h` will be reflected into the object modules.

Comment: I have another question: what if I want to do the same thing but using floats and ints inside of the mycosntant.h file?

Comment: For short `123` is an int literal, `123.5`a double, `123.5f`a float, etc. Have a look at "C constant literals" on the web.

Comment: (while this is a good demonstration, in practice everyone should get their [`M_PI` constants from `math.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/math.h.html))